# Исключение IndexOutOfBoundsException при обращении к ArrayList

Tags: java, android

Почему падает приложение при использовании функции

```
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> cacheTemp=null;
public static boolean setReturnArrayList(int comnat, ArrayList<String> temp){
        if(cacheTemp==null)return false;
        cacheTemp.set(comnat, temp); //СТРОЧКА ГДЕ ПРОИСХОДИТ ПАДЕНИЕ
        return true;
    }
```

Для работы использую `static cacheTemp` использую функции

```
public static boolean load(Context context){
    cacheTemp=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    cacheTemp.clear();
    //УКОРОЧЕННЫЙ ВАРИАНТ ДЛЯ ВОПРОСА!!!
}

public static boolean regenCache(int vsegocomnat){
    if(cacheTemp==null)return false;

    cacheTemp.clear();

    ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<vsegocomnat;i++)
    {
        setReturnArrayList(i, temp); //ЗДЕСЬ ПАДЕНИЕ ПЕРЕХОДИТ В ФУНКЦИЮ (ВВЕРХУ)
    }
    return true;
}
```

Дальше использую там где мне нужно

```
    MessagerCache.load(context); //ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИЯ (УКОРОЧЕННЫЙ ВАРИАНТ)
    MessagerCache.regenCache(10); //ЗДЕСЬ ПАДЕНИЕ
    Voider.Log(context, "getLengthComnat", String.valueOf(MessagerCache.getLengthComnat())); //НЕ ВАЖНО
    MessagerCache.save(); //НЕ ВАЖНО
```

Вот логи

> 08-19 12:24:51.707  11092-11092/ux.uchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ux.uchat/ux.uchat.Messager}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:477)
>   at ux.uchat.MessagerCache.setReturnArrayList(MessagerCache.java:84) 
>   //***УКАЗЫВАЕТ НА СТРОЧКУ (cacheTemp.set(comnat, temp); //СТРОЧКА ГДЕ ПРОИСХОДИТ ПАДЕНИЕ)***
>   at ux.uchat.MessagerCache.regenCache(MessagerCache.java:68)
>   at ux.uchat.MessagerVoider.UpdateListChat(MessagerVoider.java:41)
>   at ux.uchat.Messager.onCreate(Messager.java:25)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5122)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0  - указывает, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива которого не существует. Вы пытаетесь заменить элемент с индексом 0, но его ещё не существует. Размер массива 0. Для добавления элемента используйте метод add().

Comment: Хм странно, я думал что сетер должен сам разобратся с этим, кстате пробовал функцию одну но она всегда возвращала true, что в ней не то или все нормально

Comment: `    public static boolean getBooleanComnat(int comnat){
        if(cacheTemp==null)return false;
        if(cacheTemp.contains(comnat))return true;
        return true;
    }`

Comment: А все заметил ошибку, два раза true

Comment: А, все работает, буду внимательнее с логами)  Вот итог     public static boolean setReturnArrayList(int comnat, ArrayList<String> temp){
        if(cacheTemp==null)return false;
        if(getBooleanComnat(comnat)) {
            cacheTemp.set(comnat, temp);
        }else cacheTemp.add(comnat, temp);
        return true;
    }